# ParseFile on Android

Tags: android, parsing

I'm using the Parse SDK to build my app.

I can easily get a Bitmap out of the gallery by using Intents. I want to use them as a profile picture for my users.

However, in order to upload it I must convert it into a byte array. Also, when I download it it comes in the form of a byte array, and I must convert it back to a Drawable.

In order to convert it into a byte array, I'm doing this:

```
public static byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bmp)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
```

I cannot find how to convert this byte[] back into a Bitmap without having to save it first. How can this process be achieved?

Comment: Anyway to get the code showing how you uploaded the image? I can't seem to get the image saved to a ParseUser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do the following:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Comment: I feel dumb as hell. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
  Bitmap  bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```